# LoadRunner _ SAP_GUI_VA01_orderCreation

Tags: loadrunner, sap-gui

I'm having one issue:

My task is to fill 100 lines (articles) in sap gui, having T-code VA01.

I did a loop :

```
for(n=0;n<=99;n++)
        
    {
        
    lr_save_int(n,"lineitem");
    
    sapgui_table_set_text("({lineitem}, 'Article')", 
        "usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY"
        ":SAPMV45A:4400/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/"
        "tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG", 
        "{lineitem}", 
        "1", 
        "{P_Article}", 
        BEGIN_OPTIONAL, 
//          originalid1, 
//          "AdditionalInfo=sapgui1036", 
        END_OPTIONAL);
    
    sapgui_table_set_text("({lineitem}, 'Order Quantity')", 
        "usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY"
        ":SAPMV45A:4400/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/"
        "tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG", 
        "{lineitem}", 
        "2", 
        "{P_Qty}", 
        BEGIN_OPTIONAL, 
//          originalid2, 
//          "AdditionalInfo=sapgui1037", 
        END_OPTIONAL);

    sapgui_table_set_text("({lineitem}, 'Un')", 
        "usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY"
        ":SAPMV45A:4400/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/"
        "tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG", 
        "{lineitem}", 
        "3", 
        "{P_Unit}", 
        BEGIN_OPTIONAL, 
//          originalid3, 
//          "AdditionalInfo=sapgui1038", 
        END_OPTIONAL);

        lr_output_message("xbf order type is %s \n",lr_eval_string("{P_Article}"));
        fprintf(file,"xbf order type is %s \n",lr_eval_string("{P_Article}"));
            
}
```

My issue is this:

Because SAP Gui is having just 16 rows "available", the script is able just to fill those 16 rows, and fail.(attached ss from sap gui)

Any approach to go further when i hit the las row from sa gui.

Thanks!
Liviu

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you record adding 18 items through SAPGUI and see what happens in your captured script code?  That will most likely provide insight into how to address your challenge of moving beyond 16 rows